# Line up divs using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make sure each span lines up with the span that is on top of it but I also want the width of each span to be only be as wide as the text. I have tried to set a width on the `.skills-wrapper` but that makes the span the same width. How can I accomplish this with flexbox preferably?

```css
.skills-blobs-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  max-width: auto;
  color: darkgray;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-blobs">
  <div class="skills-blobs-block">

    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Woodwork<i class="ics-close fn"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Textile</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Painting</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Garden</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere else but I can't find the answer. If it's a duplicate, please mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `flex:1` in `.skills-wrapper` and `display:inline-flex` in `span`...

Also `max-width: auto` is not a valid value...so better to remove it

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.skills-blobs-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkgray;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.skills-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-blobs">
  <div class="skills-blobs-block">
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Woodwork<i class="ics-close fn"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Textile</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Painting</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Garden</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex:1` to `.skills-wrapper` and make it a flex container too:

```css
.skills-blobs-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.skills-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  color: darkgray;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills-blobs">
  <div class="skills-blobs-block">

    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Woodwork<i class="ics-close fn"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Textile</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Painting</span>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-wrapper">
      <span class="skills-blobs-individual">Garden</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```